# how to type vector symbol in another way

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, vector

Is there any other way for vector symbol for a quantity, which looks better than these two results.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \Large
Using vector
\[\vec{\nabla}\]
Using right arrow
\[\overrightarrow {\nabla}\]    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since "better" is a matter of taste, could you please explain what output you are seeking?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat in first result you will find that vector sign is very small compare to nabla. In the second result vector sign is very close to nabla.

Comment: Some people use boldface symbols for vectors :-). However, your question is very opinion based. BTW, recent `article` use `utf8` coding, so `[utf8]{inputenc}` is not noeed to load anymore. Also `amssymb` load `amsfonts`.

Comment: @Zarko Agree with your comment.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the package `esvect` (here with the vector shape option `f`):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[f]{esvect}
\begin{document}
    \Large
With the \texttt{esvect} package:
\[\vv{\nabla} \quad \vv{\imath} \quad \vv{m} \quad \vv{OM}\]   
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the default length of the vector is greater, and it extend automatically if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you like the general appearance of `\overrightarrow` but want to increase the vertical spacing to the argument. This example defines a `\myrightarrow` macro that adds a `\vphantom{\strut}` to the argument such that the argument is as large as a `\strut` (which is larger than a `\nabla`) and thus the arrow is put at a higher position.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\myrightarrow}[1]{\overrightarrow{\vphantom{\strut}#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
    \vec{\nabla}
    \quad
    \overrightarrow{\nabla}
    \quad
    \myrightarrow{\nabla}
\]
\large\[
    \vec{\nabla}
    \quad
    \overrightarrow{\nabla}
    \quad
    \myrightarrow{\nabla}
\]
\Large\[
    \vec{\nabla}
    \quad
    \overrightarrow{\nabla}
    \quad
    \myrightarrow{\nabla}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A word of caution: `\vphantom{\strut}` uses the `\strutbox`, which is initialized when the font size is changed. This construction will not work in different math styles. I believe `\mathstrut` is more appropriate.

Comment: Many times has `\nabla` special meaning, for example in Maxwell,s equations. There people mostly write it without arrows (meaning vector) over it. Just two mine (off-topic) two cents :-)

Comment: The `\strut` directive inserts an invisible, zero-width typographic "strut". Hence, `\vphantom{\strut}` is the same as `\strut`. A separate comment: I would agree with @campa that `\mathstrut` is more appropriate here than `\strut`.